# Connecting Matplotlib ListedColormap values to match specified values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make colormaps from a list of lists containing only values of `0,1,2,or 3`. I am attaching a sample of my created graph below and the code used to generate it.

I will be making over 100 of these graphs. The problem I am encountering is that some of these matrix inputs (list of lists) don't contain each of the values `(0,1,2,3)`. For example I have a list which is entirely values of `3`: `[[3,3],[3,3]]`. I would like this to plot as all blue, but because the `0,1,2` are not in the list the 3 value gets plotted as white. Is there a way I can explicitly link `0 = w, 1 = r, 2 = g, 3 = b`?

Example plot:

[image: Example of colormap created]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

line = ### This is where the list of lists goes

nrows, ncols = 34,34

image = np.array(line)
print (image)

image = image.reshape((nrows, ncols))

cmap = ListedColormap(['w','r','g','b'])

row_labels = range(nrows)
col_labels = range(ncols)
plt.matshow(image,cmap=cmap)
plt.xticks(range(ncols), col_labels)
plt.yticks(range(nrows), row_labels)
ax = plt.gca();
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-.5, 34, 1), minor=True);
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-.5, 34, 1), minor=True);

ax.grid(which='minor', color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most functions that accept a colormap, also accept arguments `vmin` and `vmax` to indicate the value that corresponds to the lowest and to the highest color.

Here is some example code to test and demonstrate the behavior:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=5, figsize=(15, 7))
for ax in axes.ravel():
    nrows, ncols = 5, 5

    vals = np.arange(4)[np.random.randint(0, 2, 4).astype(bool)]
    if len(vals) == 0:
        vals = [np.random.randint(4)]

    image = np.array(np.random.choice(vals, (nrows, ncols)))

    cmap = ListedColormap(['w', 'r', 'g', 'b'])

    ax.matshow(image, cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=3)
    ax.set_xticks(range(ncols))
    ax.set_yticks(range(nrows))
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-.5, ncols, 1), minor=True)
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-.5, nrows, 1), minor=True)

    ax.grid(which='minor', color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
    ax.tick_params(which='both', axis='both', length=0) # don't show tick marks
    ax.set_title(f'values: {vals}')

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]